# Align a shape within a different shape and naming shapes using VBA (macros) PowerPoint

Tags: vba, alignment, powerpoint

I would like to align ( in this case center)a shape( round cornered rectangle) within sharp cornered rectangle in a slide i.e the center point of both shapes should be equal using VBA without using 'Selection'.I am thinking to reference them via names(Like, wherever these two shapes come as a bunch, macro should align them) but not sure how to start.

Excuse me for the layman's explanation. Any thoughts would really be helpful and push me to start.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set up a loop to check each shape in the slide, finding if its Type is an AutoShape, then if its AutoShapeType is msoShapeRoundedRectangle or msoShapeRectangle. As each are found, you would store the name of each in a variable. If both are found then you would get the left, top, width and height measurements for each and set those values so the centers align.

```
Sub CenterShapes()
  Dim oSlide As Slide
  Dim oShape As Shape
  Dim bFoundRRect As Boolean, bFoundRect As Boolean
  Dim RRectName$, RectName$
  For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oShape In oSlide.Shapes
      If oShape.Type = msoAutoShape Then
        If oShape.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRoundedRectangle Then
          bFoundRRect = True
          RRectName$ = oShape.Name
        End If
        If oShape.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangle Then
          bFoundRect = True
          RectName$ = oShape.Name
        End If
      End If
    Next oShape
    If bFoundRRect = True And bFoundRect = True Then
      RRectVCenter = oSlide.Shapes(RRectName$).Top + (oSlide.Shapes(RRectName$).Height / 2)
      RRectHCenter = oSlide.Shapes(RRectName$).Left + (oSlide.Shapes(RRectName$).Width / 2)
      RectVCenter = oSlide.Shapes(RectName$).Top + (oSlide.Shapes(RectName$).Height / 2)
      RectHCenter = oSlide.Shapes(RectName$).Left + (oSlide.Shapes(RectName$).Width / 2)
      VDif = RRectVCenter - RectVCenter
      HDif = RRectHCenter - RectHCenter
      oSlide.Shapes(RectName$).Top = oSlide.Shapes(RectName$).Top + VDif
      oSlide.Shapes(RectName$).Left = oSlide.Shapes(RectName$).Left + HDif
    End If
  Next oSlide
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This example assumes you know, or determine with your code, the names of the shapes you want to align. Then it's a quick manner of setting up a [`ShapeRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shaperange) and using the built-in alignment functions in PowerPoint.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AlignMe()
    Dim theseShapeNames As Variant
    theseShapeNames = Array("Rectangle 3", "Rectangle 4", "Rectangle 5")

    Dim thisSlide As Slide
    Dim theseShapes As ShapeRange
    Set thisSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    Set theseShapes = thisSlide.Shapes.Range(theseShapeNames)
    theseShapes.Align msoAlignCenters, msoFalse
End Sub
```